# change the color of an align environment

Tags: color, align

regarding this documentation

ftp://tug.org/tex-archive/info/math/voss/mathCol/mathCol.pdf

it should be easy to change the color of an align environment like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color,amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}\color{red}
x &= 1\\
y &= 2
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

But all that changes to red is the first entry, i.e. the x.
I use MiKTeX 2.8 on Windows XP.

Any ideas?

Comment: @PeterGrill I was not aware of TeX.SE and I don't have an account there. Since I found quit a few questions about LaTeX here on Stackoverflow I thoungt I can ask LaTeX stuff here too?!

If this questions really shouldn't be here how can I migrate it?

Comment: I'd recommend you post future questions at TeX.SE. This should get migrated as I have flagged it. You should create an account there -- I think it is only one click to get the same account to be able to access both sites.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Each cell within the `align` environment forms a group, localizing the extent of the colour change. If you wrap the colour change around the outside of `align`, it spans across the internal cells:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{xcolor,amsmath}
\begin{document}
{\color{red}\begin{align}
x &= 1\\
y &= 2
\end{align}}
\end{document}
```

You'll notice that this sets even the equation numbers in `\color{red}`. This is easily fixed by adding the following to your preamble:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\math@cr@@@align}% <cmd>
  {\place@tag}% <search>
  {\bgroup\color{black}\place@tag\egroup}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\makeatother
```

The above [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox)-patch inserts a `black` colour-change around the number-printing mechanism `\place@tag`:

[image]

For individual colour modifications to each cell/component of the line, insert `\color{<colour>}` in the respective cells you want to use colour `<colour>`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Problem solved. But I'm still curious if the manual I linked is wrong and always has been or if at the time it was written things with align and color worked differently...

Comment: @FlorianMans: Which of the equations in the document are you referring to? If it is the equation marked (7) (p 4), then the code is exactly correct and corresponds to the output. Note that even though the author uses `align`, he uses the `CD` environment rather than `align` internals. As such, `\color{blue}` spans the entire equation.

Comment: Yes I was referring to equation (7). I didn't consider the `CD' environment as the important difference. Thanks again for your help and further clarification.

Comment: Is there a way to have different color per line?

Comment: @Royi: In that case, add `\color{<color>}` to each cell to specify the appropriate colour. See [this code](https://pastebin.com/raw/qhhkX57D).