# How to color certain commands/environments?

Tags: color, environments

My goal is to achieve colorings in the output document, that are similar to the syntax highlighting I use in my editor, so switching between the editing and viewing the document becomes easier on the eyes.

I figured I can use the `color` package to define some colors using `\definecolor` and then set the foreground and backgroundcolors using `\color{fg}` and `\pagecolor{bg}`, respectively.

What I'd like to do now, is assing certain colors to certain commands and environments. For simple commands like `\emph` I can do

```
\let\oldemph\emph
\renewcommand\emph[1]{{\color{emph}\oldemph{#1}}}
```

but I haven't figured out how to change the color of environments like `align*` and others.

Any help on how I could achieve this? Maybe theres even a generic way to do this, a package for semantic coloring like this would be cool.

**EDIT:** I managed to color environments using

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{align*}{\color{equation}}
\AtBeginEnvironment{align}{\color{equation}}
\AtBeginEnvironment{equation*}{\color{equation}}
\AtBeginEnvironment{equation}{\color{equation}}
```

Inline-math can be colored using `\everymath{\color{inlinemath}}`, but this overrides the colors of the `align*` environment (not of the `equation*` environment though). How to fix this?

**EDIT:** If I'm correct, `align*`-environments switch between mathmode and non-mathmode to obtain the correct spacing. So if I use `\everymath` to set a color, it will be set inside `align*` environments, overriding what I did with `\AtBeginEnvironment`. For `equation*` it works, because there is only a single math block and `\AtBeginEnvironment` will put the color setting inside. The only way I can think of to fix this, would be somehow setting a color only for `$...$`, instead of using `\everymath`. Is this possible?

Comment: Does this helps? http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/96176/27635

Comment: @karlkoeller, the answer only explains how to color a single environment, not all of its kind. Anyway, `etoolbox` patches might be able to achieve what I'm looking for, though I never used that package before.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Update below: one way to deal with `\intertext` in this method.

Normally `\everymath` only regards inline, and there is `\everydisplay` for display math. But `amsmath` typesets things in a, hmm, complicated way. In particular using `\everydisplay` to add a `\color` command seems difficult (it works when `amsmath` is not loaded). Anyway, here is a work-around:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginEnvironment{align*}{\let\SetColor\@gobble \color{display}}
\AtBeginEnvironment{align}{\let\SetColor\@gobble \color{display}}
\AtBeginEnvironment{equation*}{\let\SetColor\@gobble \color{display}}
\AtBeginEnvironment{equation}{\let\SetColor\@gobble \color{display}}
\makeatother

% maybe some other nice package has set-up things in \everymath!

\everymath\expandafter{\the\everymath\SetColor{inline}}

\definecolor{display}{rgb}{0,1,0}
\definecolor{inline}{rgb}{0,0,1}

\let\SetColor\color

\begin{document}

$xyz$

\begin{align*}
  E &= mc^2\\
  x^n+y^n&= z^n
\end{align*}

$$hello $$ %% for this we would need \everydisplay
%% but some interference with amsmath makes its use
%% a bit delicate.

\begin{equation}
  E = mc^2
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: colored math]

Update: adding to the code above in the preamble

```
\everydisplay\expandafter{\the\everydisplay\SetColor{display}}
```

will make the displayed `hello` also green. Note though that with `amsmath` this works only because its environments have been patched here to annihilate `\SetColor`. With `amsmath`, `\everydisplay {\color{green}}` causes an error. So here in `align*` the `\SetColor` does not do anything and it is the `\color` inserted at the begin of the environment which sets the color.

---

To deal with `\intertext`. One possibility.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginEnvironment{align*}{\let\SetColor\@gobble \color{display}%
                            \Patchintertext}
\AtBeginEnvironment{align}{\let\SetColor\@gobble \color{display}\Patchintertext}
\AtBeginEnvironment{equation*}{\let\SetColor\@gobble \color{display}}
\AtBeginEnvironment{equation}{\let\SetColor\@gobble \color{display}}

\def\Patchintertext{\let\oldintertext@\intertext@
                    \def\intertext@{\oldintertext@\Patchintertext@}}
\def\Patchintertext@ {\let\oldintertext\intertext
                      \def\intertext ##1{\oldintertext
                      {\color{black}\let\SetColor\color ##1}}}
\makeatother


\everymath\expandafter{\the\everymath\SetColor{inline}}
\everydisplay\expandafter{\the\everydisplay\SetColor{display}}

\definecolor{display}{rgb}{.6,.6,.2}
\definecolor{inline}{rgb}{0,0,1}

\let\SetColor\color

\begin{document}

here is some text before with $xyz$ math inline,
\begin{align*}
  E &= mc^2\\
\intertext {this is some intertext with math $a^n+b^n=c^n$ inside,}
  x^n+y^n&= z^n\quad \text{(display)}
\end{align*}
and here is some more text after with again $A^B$ math inline.

$$this is some standard math display$$ 

\begin{equation}
  E = mc^2
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image: color certain B]

Comment: This works great! There is only one problem left: `\intertext` inside an `align*` environment will be green and even `$...$` inside the intertext will be green instead of blue.

Comment: patch intertext to work in a group (perhaps it does already, I don't know) and to reset there the color to black and `\let\Setcolor\color` to deal with the `$..$` inside the intertext.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that, could you be a little more specific or provide a MWE?

Answer (score 4):

Note that you're grouping the `\color` command to limit the scope. The same would be required for an environment. This translates to inserting the `\color` command inside the environment (possibly skipping any arguments passed to it (optional/mandatory). So yes, in general, this can be done, but it depends on the type of environment and/or it's structure.

For a generic environment that doesn't accept optional or mandatory arguments (this includes starred versions), you could just use

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox,xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{etoolbox,xcolor}
\newenvironment{myenv}
  {\itshape}
  {}
\begin{document}
Here is some text.

\begin{myenv}
Here is some more text.
\end{myenv}

Here is some text.

\appto{\myenv}{\color{red}}
\begin{myenv}
Here is some more text.
\end{myenv}

Here is some text.
\end{document}
```

The above `app`ends code `to` the environment starting command (note that an environment `myenv` actually consists of the pair `\myenv`...`\endmyenv`). However, if your macro takes an optional command

```
\begin{myenv}[<something>]
  % <stuff>
\end{myenv}
```

then the above might work and might not... depending on how you've defined the conditioning on the optional argument. For example, the following does not work with the `\appto` approach from [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox):

```
\newenvironment{myenv}[1][\itshape]
  {#1}
  {}
```

Why? It all depends on how/when TeX reads an assesses the input.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox,xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{etoolbox,xcolor}
\newenvironment{myenv}[1][\itshape]
  {#1}
  {}
\begin{document}
Here is some text.

\begin{myenv}
Here is some more text.
\end{myenv}

Here is some text.

\appto{\myenv}{\color{red}}
\begin{myenv}
Here is some more text.
\end{myenv}

Here is some text.

\begin{myenv}[\bfseries]
Here is some more text.
\end{myenv}

Here is some text.
\end{document}
```

As can be seen from the above example, `[\bfseries]` (the optional argument to `myenv`) is read as-is without even considering it an optional argument, since it prints `[]`, in *italics* and **bold** (the second `]`). The insertion via `\appto` interferes with the optional argument, so one has to insert it at a later point. For this one could use `etoolbox`'s `\AtBeginEnvironment`, if needed, or create a pseudo-environment which wraps itself around the original one, passing the appropriate options/arguments and inserting the `\color` command at the appropriate location.

Comment: Using `\AtBeginEnvironment` pretty much solves this in an elegant way. But I still have a problem with the color I define with `\everymath` for `$...$` being applied to `align*` as well, see my recent edit.

Comment: @ChristophPegel: Not exactly sure, but [`\everymath` and author color](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/100263/5764) may be relevant.